# Mongoose query to find documents where dates don't match within the same document

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am trying to write a mongoose query that can find all documents where `REVIEW_DATE` is within the last 24 hours and there is no action in the actions array that matches `TYPE`, `DETAIL_TYPE`, and `ACTION_DATE` does not match `REVIEW_DATE`. Basically if REVIEW_DATE changes, I need to re-perform the action, so the value of the review date is recorded in the actionDetails.

```
{
   reviewDate: <REVIEW_DATE>,
   actions: [
      {
         actionType: <TYPE>,
         actionDetails: {
            detailType: <DETAIL_TYPE>,
            valueOfReviewDateAtTimeOfAction: <ACTION_DATE>
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Because mongo doesn't support a self join, I am pulling back all documents where REVIEW_DATE is within the last 24 hours and then iterating through the results filtering the list by iterating over the list of actions. Is there a way do do this with a single query or aggregation?

Answer (score 1):

If I got your question correctly, I believe that you need to generate a query that uses the [`$expr`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/) operator as it allows you to use aggregate pipeline expressions within the same document such as

- [`$dateDiff`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateDiff/) - get the difference between two dates and determine wether the `<REVIEW_DATE>` is within the last 24 hours using a system aggregation variable [`$$NOW`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/#variable.NOW) as reference to the current datetime value
- [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) - filter the `actions` array to return only those elements that match the given conditions
- [`$size`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/) - returns the length of the filtered `actions` array
- [`$gt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/gt/)/[`$lt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lt/) - returns a bool that is used for the [`$expr`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/) condition to determine whether the filtered array has elements or not that satisfy the above query criteria on the same document.

For example, you could try running the following query:

```
Model.find({ 
    $expr: {
        $and: [
            { $lt: [
                { $dateDiff: { 
                    startDate: '$reviewDate', 
                    endDate: '$$NOW', 
                    unit: 'hour' 
                } }, 
                24 
            ] },
            { $gt: [
                { $size: { 
                    $filter: { 
                        input: '$actions',
                        cond: {
                            $and: [
                                { $ne: [
                                    '$reviewDate', 
                                    '$$this.actionDetails.valueOfReviewDateAtTimeOfAction'
                                ] },
                                { $ne: [
                                    '$$this.actionType', 
                                    '$$this.actionDetails.detailType'
                                ] },
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                } }, 
                0 
            ] }
        ]
    }
})
```

or for MongoDB versions which do not have support for [`$dateDiff`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateDiff/)

```
Model.find({ 
    $expr: {
        $and: [
            { $lt: [
                new Date(Date.now() - 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24), 
                '$reviewDate' 
            ] },
            { $gt: [
                { $size: { 
                    $filter: { 
                        input: '$actions',
                        cond: {
                            $and: [
                                { $ne: [
                                    '$reviewDate', 
                                    '$$this.actionDetails.valueOfReviewDateAtTimeOfAction'
                                ] },
                                { $ne: [
                                    '$$this.actionType', 
                                    '$$this.actionDetails.detailType'
                                ] },
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                } }, 
                0 
            ] }
        ]
    }
})
```